# Algorithms question: Largest contiguous subset selection

Tags: algorithms, divide-and-conquer

Q. Given two arrays, $A$ and $B$, of equal length, find the largest possible contiguous subset of indices $[i,j]$ such that $\max(A[i: j]) < \min(B[i: j])$.

Example: $A = [10, 21, 5, 1, 3], B = [3, 1, 4, 23, 56]$.

Explanation: $A[4] = 1, A[5] = 3$, $B[4] = 23, B[5] = 56$, $\max(A[4], A[5]) < \min(B[4], B[5])$.

The indices are $[4,5]$ (inclusive), and the largest contiguous subset has size 2.

I can do this in $O(n^2)$ brute force method but cannot seem to reduce the time complexity. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

O(n) solution:

Move index `j` from left to right and drag `i` behind so that the window from `i` to `j` is valid. So always increase `j` by 1, and then increase `i` as much as needed for the window to be valid.

To do that, keep a queue `Aq` of indexes of non-increasing A-values. Then `A[Aq[0]]` tells you the max A-value in the window. Similarly, keep a queue for non-decreasing B-values.

For each new `j`, first update `Aq` and `Bq` according to the new A-value and new B-value. Then, while the window is invalid, increase `i` and drop `Aq[0]` and `Bq[0]` if they're `i`. When both `j` and `i` are updated, update the result with the window size `j - i - 1`.

Python implementation:

```
def solution(A, B):
    Aq = deque()
    Bq = deque()
    i = 0
    maxlen = 0
    for j in range(len(A)):
        while Aq and A[Aq[-1]] < A[j]:
            Aq.pop()
        Aq.append(j)
        while Bq and B[Bq[-1]] > B[j]:
            Bq.pop()
        Bq.append(j)
        while Aq and A[Aq[0]] >= B[Bq[0]]:
            if Aq[0] == i:
                Aq.popleft()
            if Bq[0] == i:
                Bq.popleft()
            i += 1
        maxlen = max(maxlen, j - i + 1)
    return maxlen
```

Test results from comparing against a naive brute force reference solution:

```
expect:  83   result:  83   same: True
expect: 147   result: 147   same: True
expect: 105   result: 105   same: True
expect:  71   result:  71   same: True
expect: 110   result: 110   same: True
expect:  56   result:  56   same: True
expect: 140   result: 140   same: True
expect: 109   result: 109   same: True
expect:  86   result:  86   same: True
expect: 166   result: 166   same: True
```

Testing code ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVPRbqMwEHznK/attkorSHrSKSqV8G9E0YkjptkUbMc4d62qfntujV1CiHK8sLuzMx57bfPhdlotfxp7OjVWd@Cwk@gAO6Oti1kyILZSW/pFpN5prGUfoFq3rawdatV/41t5OMqAopPWad2OWK2736iqoT9JtrKBXrdHn7IyBcFXCdBXHqAIMowPBTEvIOXZEHXVeyvVmDbawh5Qec@vkhHESh5l/fd3h630C9CWoFyXh/VDvtnAM8X7zbktuHg02sQFY6EyRqot2/OZoAiCYi2i4AvFc0ExFxS3BacOM69XBHGKL0WxgaEFigLwEjpvopWNm6wbeeI/PHGTB/cF5GNpPH4KWEhSGsCD74M8UK10R6tia5i6qvCPnI783MPYSL9y5aeLaRjw9Cqxi2mnsOBXVNqvFy/XuNrf5xtOI@9QMfGd83ROIZ/VsXVFxpPEL/zrfK3yLNr2O/@RhatXUhzfRvTztCAvb4WKl/gKzxfLp2mHfDf0lqhtcjzxdHpyQsDlaxkwY1E51twF8go@Y7D8GolUjMFQ7KtOjiU//8D4uuOn0z8))

```
from timeit import timeit
from random import choices
from collections import deque
from itertools import combinations

def solution(A, B):
    Aq = deque()
    Bq = deque()
    i = 0
    maxlen = 0
    for j in range(len(A)):
        while Aq and A[Aq[-1]] < A[j]:
            Aq.pop()
        Aq.append(j)
        while Bq and B[Bq[-1]] > B[j]:
            Bq.pop()
        Bq.append(j)
        while Aq and A[Aq[0]] >= B[Bq[0]]:
            if Aq[0] == i:
                Aq.popleft()
            if Bq[0] == i:
                Bq.popleft()
            i += 1
        maxlen = max(maxlen, j - i + 1)
    return maxlen

def naive(A, B):
    return max((j - i + 1
                for i, j in combinations(range(len(A)), 2)
                if max(A[i:j+1]) < min(B[i:j+1])),
               default=0)

for _ in range(10):
    n = 500
    A = choices(range(42), k=n)
    B = choices(range(1234), k=n)
    expect = naive(A, B)
    result = solution(A, B)
    print(f'expect: {expect:3}   result: {result:3}   same: {result == expect}')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the problem in $O(n \log n)$ time. Construct a data structure $D_A$ that can answer queries of the following form in constant time: given two indices $i \in \{1,\dots,n\}$ and $j \in \{i,\dots,n\}$, report $\max_{h=i,\dots,j} A[h]$. This can be done in time $O(n)$.
Similarly, construct a data structure $D_B$ that can report $\min_{h=i,\dots,j} B[h]$. Have a look at [this paper](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/10719839_9) for details.

For each index $i=1,\dots, n$ such that $A[i]<B[i]$, find the largest index $j \ge i$ such that $M_i(j)=\max_{h=i,\dots,j} A[h] $ is smaller than $m_i(j) = \min_{h=i,\dots,j} B[h] $.
You can do so by noticing that $M_i(\cdot)$ is monotonically non-decreasing while $m_i(\cdot)$ is monotonically non-increasing. This implies that $\forall j' \le j, M_i(j')<m_i(j')$ and that $\forall j'>j, M_i(j') \ge m_i(j')$. As a consequence you can use binary search to find $j$ with only $O(\log n)$ queries to $D_A$ and $D_B$.
Consider $(i,j)$ as a candidate solution.

Finally, among all the candidate pairs $(i,j)$, return one of those  that maximize $j-i$ (if any).

Answer (score 0):

The idea is once you have parsed a part of the 2 arrays and got a subsequence *i,j* then no go through it again as we already know the result

*A[i-j]≤B[i-j]*  (that what kept the loop going)

and *A[j+1]>B[j+1]*  (that what stopped it)

Then we keep the length of this interval in a variable, say  *max*  and start checking for a longer sequence starting from  *j+2*

A Pseudocode could be

i=j=0;

N= array_size;

While(i<N)

{

While (A[j]≤B[j)AND(j<N) j++;

*//now A[j]>B[j]*

If ((j-i) > max) { Res.str=i;
Res.end=j-1;}

i=j+1;

}

Comment: Welcome COMPUTER **SCIENCE** @SE. I think the indentation of your *Pseudocode* looks strange even when using ` ` "digit blanks". The two blanks to create an effective line break need to *precede* it: append them to the line before.